# EditorFor .no need to show label

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

```
<td class="editor-label">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender)
</td>
<td class="editor-field">
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gender)
</td>
```

I have this in my view.

but at this time i am seeing

```
<td class="editor-label">
   <label for="Deaseased_Gender">Gender</label>
</td>
<td class="editor-field">
   <div class="fieldContainer">
      <span class="fieldLabel">
         Gender        <text>:</text>
      </span>
      <div class="editorField">
         <input id="Deaseased_Gender" name="Deaseased.Gender" type="text" value="" />
      </div>
   </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

At this time  I am seeing Gender twice [image: see the image here]

what can i do to avoid the auto generated text  'Gender'  ,but need to keep EditorFor with out change?

Comment: Did you create an custom editor for the Gender property?

Comment: No,see i have a  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender)

Comment: @user444569, where does `<div class="fieldContainer">` come from? That's not a standard template. You must have some custom editor template for the `Gender` property.

Comment: @user444569 - yeah, I see that...  the point is that below that you're calling `EditorFor` and that, conveniently enough, will use an editor template for the type of Gender if you've got one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my guess.  This part:

```
<div class="fieldContainer">
   <span class="fieldLabel">
      Gender        <text>:</text>
   </span>
   <div class="editorField">
      <input id="Deaseased_Gender" name="Deaseased.Gender" type="text" value="" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Makes me think that you've got custom editor for the Gender property of your model.  Do you have an EditorTemplates folder, probably under Shared in your Views?  That's a convenient place to stick reusable templates to use throughout your app.

If you do and you want to use that, then you'd want to remove either the span in that which has the "Gender :" or rework things to remove the

```
<td class="editor-label">
   <label for="Deaseased_Gender">Gender</label>
</td>
```

part, but that might involve a little more work because you're mixing tables and divs then.

Comment: I Dont have custom editor for my editor for is form namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html

Comment: What is the type of Gender?  string?  I see you've got the same think for Lastname...hmm...

Comment: Do a search for "fieldContainer" in your entire solution... I think the answer will be found there.

Answer (score -2):

This is not the default behavior for EditorFor in MVC. But to overcome this problem, use "Editor Templates" for this datatype. Following are few examples.

http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-editortemplates-in-mvc-3/

http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/